# WindowManager.addView prevents other apps from setting screen brightness

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I have a simple `Activity` which adds a view to the screen. Codes are:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)this
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    View view = new customView(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(0);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.width = 0;
    params.height = 0;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 1;
    params.y = 1;
    params.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
    wm.addView(view, params);
}


public static class customView extends View {

    public customView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
  }
}​
```

Strange thing is after the view is added some apps (e.g. MX Player) cannot set screen brightness any more!

Dose anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you will not addview by windowmanager because windowmanager will interact with many things, such as activity, if you want to addview to the activity domaticly, you should use a Control like viewpager or simply use viewgroup to addview

Comment: Thank you! But I want the view to be added in front of other apps.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html   whether this can help you